# How to prevent AngularJs from setting model value to null when element is hidden?

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="model.typeId" ng-show="AllowToChangeType(model)" 
        ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in model.types">
</select>
```

The issue is that when the user clicks <kbd>Save</kbd> button, the form is regenerated to non-editable mode, `AllowToChangeType()` returns `false`, and as this `<select>` becomes hidden, `model.typeId` gets set to `null`. Then, if the user clicks on <kbd>Edit</kbd> again, this `<select>` is regenerated, but nothing is selected in it, although the data has been saved correctly. Ideally, the `<select>` should show the saved value. How to solve this issue?

Comment: This question does not have enough information to reproduce the problem. It needs the code for the `save` and `edit` buttons. The `ng-show` directive does not destroy DOM nodes. It only changes CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making some incorrect assumptions. `ng-show` does not remove the model value when the element is hidden, as this plunker proves: https://plnkr.co/edit/knnLRZcHdQukGawU8iyJ?p=preview

`ng-show`/`ng-hide` do not regenerate DOM elements, they simply change visibility property